Is there a best practice around sharing a role with multiple namespaces or services?
I noticed that in our cluster, we have dozens of roles which are identical if you ignore unique fields like creationTimestamp, uid, resourcesVersion, labels, name and namespace:
The following will dump all the roles in the cluster into one file per role after deleting the unique fields:
kubectl get roles -A -o json | jq -c '.items[] | map(del(.. | .creationTimestamp?, .uid?, .resourceVersion?, .labels?, .name?, .namespace?))' | split -l 1

And then counting files with identical content:
❯ md5sum *|  awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1'
  73 9ced71c5d581cde3c4e94c542ca58f42
  11 d7f556fbe1b2f62ae931b735ebe75349

I was wondering what would be pros vs cons for replacing these identical roles by a single ClusterRole which is then bound where it's needed.
I suppose that it's cleaner to have fewer redundant resources in the cluster, but would it push me into a corner that will make me regret it in the future?

Eliminates redundancy but I guess it could come back to bite you if you need to apply specific labels, annotations, or slightly different permissions for roles in certain namespaces in the future.

@hakim00 thanks for your thoughts.
Wouldn't this be mitigated by sharing the cluster role as long as it's viable and just switch "snowflakes" to a separate role if and when the need comes up?
